# comparing a value from an array with an int

Tags: php

i got an array like this

```
$ratings =
[
   [   'text' => 'bla',
       'author' => 'Ute U.',
       'stars' => 2
   ],
   [   'text' => 'bla2',
       'author' => 'Ute a.',
       'stars' => 4
   ]
]
```

Its obvious that the value behind 'stars' is an integer.
But how do I compare that value with any number?
What i tried, and doesn't work is

```
foreach ($ratings as $rating)
{
        
        if ($rating['stars'] == 5)
        {
            $showRatings[] = $rating;
        }
}
```

The assigning line isnt the problem, i am sure of that since all other code not regarding the comparism works with this line.

I ofc also tried 12 other solution from various sites.. it never ever works..

Please help a brother out here.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/sShjr4kUPO88HkQ7eUeL3g in this page you can see the code you shared works fine.

Comment: Add a line with $showRatings = []; before the line with foreach so that you get an empty array if no case applies.

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine the value is never 5 in your example so the condition is never true.

Comment: yeah to be fair that was a bad example in the real array there are 5s:D the code is actually quite more complex and i boiled it down the wrong way..

Answer (score 1):

This should work... I've tried it and its working fine for me.

```
$ratings =
[
   [   'text' => 'bla',
       'author' => 'Ute U.',
       'stars' => 4
   ],
   [   'text' => 'bla2',
       'author' => 'Ute a.',
       'stars' => 5
   ]
];

$showRatings = array();

foreach ($ratings as $rating)
{
    foreach($rating as $key=>$value){
        if($key=='stars' && $value==5){
            $showRatings[] = $rating;
        }
    }
}

print_r($showRatings);
```